# Application Authentication

Tags: authentication, integrity, appsec

We are developing an Android/iOS app. This app tracks the user's GPS coordinates and send them to the server along with other data. The integrity of the sent data is too critical for our service. We would like to confirm that the data is actually coming from our app and not from the user as he/she can send fake data. Encryption alone can be defeated by reverse engineering to extract the required keys. Is there a way to authenticate the application itself?

Kind regards

Comment: How capable do you estimate the users are? i.e. are they able to inspect your binaries on their system and possibly modify them, or to sniff network communications in any way?

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not without being a device administrator and locking down a bunch of stuff on the phone.  Android very intentionally supports fake GPS information for debugging purposes and as far as I know, you would need to be able to disable that, which would be difficult if not impossible to do without being a device administrator and even then wouldn't necessarily be guaranteed.

Elaborate setups could even potentially spoof GPS data with actual radio waves as a high tech hack to it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using hybrid locational services to validate your GPS inputs.  This Wikipedia page on Wi-Fi location services should be a good start - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system